# Flutter build_runner with auto_route seems to just pause and then fails after several minutues without spitting out any information until failue

Tags: flutter, dart

As per the subject line, when I run "flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs". Does anyone have any suggestion on what I am missing? it does run in another project so it seems to be specific to this project.

The current dependency list is have is:

environment:
sdk: '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
bloc: ^8.1.0
flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
equatable: ^2.0.5
intl: ^0.18.0
formz: ^0.4.0
uuid: ^3.0.4
shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
flutter_secure_storage: ^8.0.0

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
auto_route: ^5.0.4
auto_route_generator: ^5.0.3

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
build_runner: ^2.3.3

flutter pub cache repair
dart pub get
flutter pub get

uninstalling and reinstalling
build_runner, auto_route, and auto_route_generator.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like auto_route_generator is in your dependencies, but I think it should be in your dev dependencies.

Comment: Same result occurs if I move auto_route_generator to my dev dependencies.